# Calculate angles of an isosceles triangle knowing only the length of the base

Tags: triangles

Is there a way to find the angles of an isosceles triangle if you only know the length of the base? Here's an image:

[isosceles triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipCPW.png)

If I know the length in red, is it possible to figure out what the angles in purple are?

Probably not, so in that case, let's then say I know the lengths of the black lines if the first is impossible.

Comment: There are many isosceles triangles with the same base, hence the first question is trivial. The second question is trivial as well: if you know the side lengths of a triangle, you also know its angles by the cosine theorem.

Comment: The isosceles triangle happens to be an extra-specially easy application of the cosine theorem, because the perpendicular bisector of the base divides the isosceles triangle into two congruent right triangles.